# Finding the number of ways I can split a list into two parts so that each item in the left part is smaller than each item in the right part

Tags: python, dynamic, dynamic-programming

Algorithm for finding the number of ways I can split a list into two parts so that each item in the left part is smaller than each item in the right part.

Currently, I have the following function, but this doesn't quite work... Also, I would need to be able to do this in O(n) which this one isn't since the nested loop...

```
def get_subsets(l): 
   n = len(l) 
   subsets = [] 
   for i in range(n + 2): 
       for j in range(i + 2, n + 1): 
           if l[i:j][-1] > l[i:j][-2]:
              subsets.append(l[i:j]) 
   return subsets
```

For example for the input `[2,1,2,5,7,6,9]` there would be 3 ways `[2,1,2], [5,7,6,9]`,  `[2,1,2,5], [7,6,9]`, `[2,1,2,5,7,6], [9].`

My current function only returns

```
[[2, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 2, 5],
 [2, 1, 2, 5, 7],
 [2, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 5, 7],
 [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9],
 [2, 5],
 [2, 5, 7],
 [2, 5, 7, 6, 9],
 [5, 7],
 [5, 7, 6, 9],
 [7, 6, 9],
 [6, 9]]
```

for this... What kind of modifications should I make?

Answer (score 2):

**Goal:**

> ... such that each item in the left part is smaller than each item in the right part

To achieve this goal,

1. Each item in left part should be strictly smaller than "minimum" item in the right partition.
2. Each item in right part should be bigger than "maximum" item in the left partition.

Reducing the 2 steps further, it is enough to check that:

- Maximum item in the left partition is strictly smaller than Minimum item in the right partition.

**Note**: Now looking at your example, it seems we are only  looking for left prefix and right suffixes partitions consuming entire list following our goal.

**Bruteforce (O(N * N * N) time and O(1) space complexity):**

```
def get_subsets(l): 
   n = len(l)
   subsets = [] 
   for i in range(1, n):  # O(N) time
     if max(l[:i]) < min(l[i:]): # O(N) time for min and max functions
        subsets.append(l[:i]) # O(N) time to add answers
        subsets.append(l[i:])
   return subsets
```

**Analysis of Bruteforce:**

`max` and `min` operations together are O(N) as the total numbers in the array are N and we operate on all the numbers and there is also an outer loop of O(N). Since we also want the subsets, creating and adding subsets involve extra O(N) time. So the total runtime complexity becomes O(N * N * N) in the worst case when the elements are in sorted order.

**Scope for improvement in runtime:** Can we somehow calculate maximum item of a left partition and minimum item of a right partition in O(1) time? Yes we can achieve this by precalculating minimum for all possible right partitions. But this comes at the cost of O(N) extra space. We will be calculating maximum item of left partition on the fly while iterating.

**Optimized runtime (O(N * N) time and O(N) space complexity):**

```
def get_subsets(l): 
   n = len(l)
   subsets = []
   
   # precalculation step begin
   min_suffix = l.copy() # min_suffix[i] is minimum item after index i including i 
   for i in range(n-2,-1,-1):
      min_suffix[i] = min(min_suffix[i+1], l[i])
   # precalculation step end

   max_prefix_till_now = l[0] # we will maintain maximum item seen till now and update on the fly

   for i in range(1, n): 
     if max_prefix_till_now < min_suffix[i]:
        subsets.append(l[:i])
        subsets.append(l[i:])
     max_prefix_till_now = max(max_prefix_till_now, l[i]) # update maximum on the fly
   return subsets
```